# Symplectic Submanifolds of Contact Manifolds and Contact Submanifolds of Symplectic Manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

We know every contact manifold admits a symplectic submanifold, e.g., by Giroux's bijection : if $\omega$ is a contact form for a 3-manifold $M^3$ , then $d \omega$ is symplectic on the fibers of the open book associated to the contact structure $(M^3 , \omega)$. Now, if we are given a symplectic manifold $M^{2n}$: when does $M^{2n}$ admit a contact submanifold? I think it has to see with the existence of a Liouville vector field, but I am not sure. Thanks for any answers, refs., etc.

Comment: You can hope for a hypersurface and a chosen primitive for $\omega$ in a neighborhood of it. This is in the spirit of the "canonical" example $(M,\lambda)\subset (\mathbb{R}\times M,d(e^s\lambda))$.

Comment: Thanks, can this be extended to higher dimensions, i.e. 4-or-higher?

Answer (score 5):

As Chris Gerig indicates in his comment, the correct notion is that of a contact-type hypersurface. These always exist, even locally. You could just take the boundary of a Darboux ball, which always exists. This is a contact-type hypersurface. Or, if you can find a Lagrangian submanifold (which you always can, e.g. a small torus in a Darboux ball) then the boundary of a Weinstein neighbourhood is a contact-type hypersurface. Or, if you are in a projective variety and can find an ample normal crossing divisor Poincaré dual to the symplectic form then the boundary of a neighbourhood of the divisor is a contact-type hypersurface (see [Seidel's "A biased view of symplectic cohomology"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2055)).

Comment: The title should be "A biased view of symplectic cohomology".